# Cut vs None transition in PowerPoint

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

With the slide transition set to `None` or `Cut` (without changing effect options), Microsoft PowerPoint 2016 behaves the same way: the next slide immediately appears.

If I set the transition to `Cut`, click `Effect Options`, and click `Through Black`, the transition is different: the screen will become black for a short amount of time before showing the next slide.

Is there any real difference between `None` and `Cut` (with no effect options)? If not, then why do they both exist?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is the one you've already noted.

A cut transition is a term from video editing, and is one of the most basic forms of video transitions.

We cannot answer "why" these both exist because only the original developers could answer such a question.

Comment: As @music2myear says.  Though a guess:  None means no special transition, therefore show the user no options. Cut means that some sort of transition's been applied so the program should show the user whatever options are available, even if it's just the one "through black" option.  Note that the Duration option also becomes available when you choose Cut.

Comment: Cut is a type of transition. You cut "through" something and for a given amount of time. There are other transitions besides cut, such as wipe, fade, slide, etc.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg but the Duration setting has no effect with Cut. It should.

Comment: It may depend on version; in the latest version (365/Insider/mid-August 2020), Duration does have an effect if you apply Through Black effect. When you go to the slide, it cuts to black for the amount of Duration, then cuts to the slide. That's the Answer. As to the Question ... WHY? comes to mind. ;-)